# derivative distributions heaviside

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

hello everyone here is the exercise
Let $H$ be the Heaviside function $(H(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $H(x)=1$ if $x>0)$, and $a, b, c$ real constants. We set $f_b(x)=H(x-b)$ and $g_c(x)=(x-c) H(x-c)$.

1. Calculate $f_b^{\prime}$ and $g_c^{\prime}$ in the sense of distributions.
2. Calculate in $\mathcal{D}^{\prime}(\mathbf{R})$ the convolution product $\delta_a^{\prime \prime} * \delta_b^{\prime}$.
3. Calculate in $\mathcal{D}^{\prime}(\mathbf{R})$ the convolution products:
   $$
   \delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c, \quad \delta_a^{\prime \prime} * \delta_b^{\prime} * \delta_c, \quad f_b * g_c
   $$
4. Compute convolution inverses (if well defined)
   $$
   \delta_a * \delta_b, \quad \delta_a^{\prime} * \delta_b, \quad \delta_a^{\prime} * f_b
   $$
   ////////////////////////////////////////
   here is my edit can someone tell me if it is right or not
5. Calcul de $f_b'$ et $g_c'$ au sens des distributions:
   Pour calculer les dérivées des distributions $f_b(x)$ et $g_c(x)$, nous allons utiliser la définition de la dérivée d'une distribution. Soit $\varphi(x)$ une fonction test.
   a) Calcul de $f_b'$:
   $$\langle f_b', \varphi \rangle = -\langle f_b, \varphi' \rangle$$
   $$\langle f_b', \varphi \rangle = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_b(x) \varphi'(x) dx$$
   Pour $x < b$, $f_b(x) = 0$, donc l'intégrale est nulle. Pour $x > b$, $f_b(x) = 1$, donc l'intégrale devient:
   $$\langle f_b', \varphi \rangle = -\int_{b}^{\infty} \varphi'(x) dx$$
   Par intégration par parties, nous obtenons:
   $$\langle f_b', \varphi \rangle = \varphi(b)$$
   Donc, $f_b' = \delta_b$.

b) Calcul de $g_c'$:
$$\langle g_c', \varphi \rangle = -\langle g_c, \varphi' \rangle$$
$$\langle g_c', \varphi \rangle = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_c(x) \varphi'(x) dx$$
Pour $x < c$, $g_c(x) = 0$, donc l'intégrale est nulle. Pour $x > c$, $g_c(x) = (x-c)$, donc l'intégrale devient:
$$\langle g_c', \varphi \rangle = -\int_{c}^{\infty} (x-c)\varphi'(x) dx$$
Par intégration par parties, nous obtenons:
$$\langle g_c', \varphi \rangle = -\int_{c}^{\infty} \varphi(x) dx$$
Donc, $g_c' = -\delta_c$.

2. Calcul du produit de convolution $\delta_a'' * \delta_b'$:
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta_a'', \delta_b' * \varphi \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta_a'', \delta_b'(\varphi') \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = -\langle \delta_a', \delta_b(\varphi') \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = -\langle \delta_a', -\delta_b'(\varphi) \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta_a', \delta_b'(\varphi) \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = -\langle \delta_b', \delta_a'(\varphi) \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = -\langle \delta_b', -\delta_a(\varphi') \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta_b', \delta_a(\varphi') \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta_a(\varphi'), \delta_b' \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta_a, \delta_b'(\varphi') \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta_a, -\delta_b(\varphi'') \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = -\langle \delta_a, \delta_b(\varphi'') \rangle$$
   $$\langle \delta_a'' * \delta_b', \varphi \rangle = -\langle \delta_a * \delta_b, \varphi'' \rangle$$
   Donc, $\delta_a'' * \delta_b' = -\delta_a * \delta_b''$.
3. Calcul des produits de convolution:
   a) $\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c$:
   $$\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c = \delta_a * (\delta_b * \delta_c)$$
   Utilisons la propriété de l'associativité de la convolution:
   $$\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c = (\delta_a * \delta_b) * \delta_c$$
   $$\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c = \delta_{a+b} * \delta_c$$
   $$\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c = \delta_{a+b}(\delta_c)$$
   $$\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c = \delta_{a+b}(c)$$
   $$\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c = \delta_{a+b}(c) \quad \text{(La distribution de Dirac évalue la fonction en son argument)}$$
   $$\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c = \delta_{a+b,c}$$

b)
$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c$:
$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = \delta_a'' * (\delta_b' * \delta_c)$$
Utilisons à nouveau la propriété de l'associativité de la convolution:
$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = (\delta_a'' * \delta_b') * \delta_c$$
$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = (-\delta_a * \delta_b'') * \delta_c$$
Utilisons le résultat du point 2):

$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = \delta_a * \delta_b'' * \delta_c$$
Réutilisons la propriété de l'associativité de la convolution:
$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = \delta_a * (\delta_b'' * \delta_c)$$
$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = \delta_a\delta_{b+c}$$
$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = \delta_a(\delta_{b+c})$$
$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = \delta_a(b+c)$$
$$\delta_a'' * \delta_b' * \delta_c = \delta_{a,b+c}$$

c) $f_b * g_c$:
$$f_b * g_c = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_b(x-y)g_c(y) dy$$
Pour $x < b$, $f_b(x-y) = 0$, donc l'intégrale est nulle.
Pour $x > b$, $f_b(x-y) = 1$ et $g_c(y) = (y-c)$, donc l'intégrale devient:
$$f_b * g_c = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (y-c) dy = \left[\frac{y^2}{2}-cy\right]_{\infty}^{\infty}$$
La valeur de cette intégrale est infinie, donc $f_b * g_c$ n'est pas une distribution régulière et n'appartient pas à $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbf{R})$.

4. Calcul des inverses de convolution:
   a) $\delta_a * \delta_b$:
   $$\delta_a * \delta_b = \delta_{a+b}$$
   Pour obtenir l'inverse de convolution, nous devons trouver une distribution $v$ telle que $\delta_{a+b} * v = v * \delta_{a+b} = \delta_0$. Cela implique que $v$ doit être la distribution de Dirac centrée en $-a-b$. Donc, l'inverse de convolution de $\delta_a * \delta_b$ est $\delta_{a-b}$.

b) $\delta_a' * \delta_b$:
$$\delta_a' * \delta_b = -\delta_a * \delta_b'$$
Comme nous l'avons vu précédemment, l'inverse de convolution de $\delta_a * \delta_b'$ est $-\delta_{a+b}$. Donc, l'inverse de convolution de $\delta_a' * \delta_b$ est $-\delta_{a+b}$.

c) $\delta_a' * f_b$:
$$\delta_a' * f_b = -\delta_a * f_b'$$
Nous avons calculé précédemment que $f_b' = \delta_b$. Donc, l'inverse de convolution de $\delta_a' * f_b$ est $-\delta_a * \delta_b$.

Comment: Please use only English in your posts!

Comment: Your conclusion about $g_c'$ is incorrect.

Comment: $\delta_a * \delta_b * \delta_c = \delta_{a+b,c}$ is incorrect.

Comment: $\delta_a'' * \delta_b' = -\delta_a * \delta_b''$ is incorrect.

Comment: $f_b * g_c$ actually is defined in the distributional sense. If I'm not thinking wrongly, it is even defined in the classical sense.

Comment: All convolutional inverses are incorrect.

Comment: A result like $\delta_a'' * \delta_b' = -\delta_a * \delta_b''$ is not only incorrect, it is also like asking for $2\times 6$ and giving $3\times 4$ as the result. Just as the expected answer to the latter question is $12$, the expected answer to the convolution is $\delta_{a+b}'''.$